# TortoiseSVN and Visual Studio Express 2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio, svn

I'm using TotoiseSVN client and Assembla backend in a VS 2010 express project. We have issues with VS folders (or filters) dropping and files sometimes not being added to the project. I notice when I commit the .vcxproj and .vcxproj.filters files are never checked by default even though they should be changing. So I manually check them and told others to as well when they commit.

This can lead to issues if team member A checks out, only changes some code, while team member B has the project checked out and added files to the project. If team member B then commits BEFORE team member A, team member A's project file doesn't have the new files team member B added so now his project overwrites team members B's project file he checked in and now the new added files aren't in the project.

How do we get around this besides having amazing coordination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[CMake](http://www.cmake.org) is perfect for this.

In case you haven't come across CMake, it allows you to create your entire project's build files in a separate directory to your source files, outside of svn altogether.

A single CMakeLists.txt file in your repository's root would replace all your current .vcxproj and .filters files.

Comment: So this is basically a standard issue with SVN? I'm not a huge make guy, which is why I love VS's project layout. Even if the source control code is an add-in to VS I would think this could still be an issue, but I never seem to have this problem with TFS at work.

Comment: I think it's a common issue with any vcs.  You always have to have some degree of interaction between devs to resolve vcs conflicts, but removing the build files from the vcs helps avoid some of these from being issues in the first place.  I'm not a make guy either, but the CMake syntax is relatively straightforward, the documentation is good, and perhaps most importantly, the mailing list is almost always helpful and fast.

Comment: This is valid so I'll accept it. I've posted on the Assembla forums and they said we should always do an update before a commit to help avoid this issue. Thanks for the alternative idea.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect what may be happening here is that the developers aren't saving the project files when adding new files to them.  VS2008 did this by default, but I think that in VS2010 they aren't saved until you explicitly do File -> Save All.  As a result it means that the changes are not getting committed.  Once your devs *do* get in the habit of saving the project files before committing then SVN will in 99% of the time handle all the merges for you. The remaining 1% of the time is when someone has done some more major restructuring of the project file or two people have made conflicting changes to the build settings. In these cases you'd have to resolve them by hand.

SVN will never overwrite one person's changes with another, it will always try to merge. So if you're running into this problem it suggests that one person is somehow rolling back someone else's changes, or they don't have the option in Visual Studio set to reload files when changed externally: `Tools -> Options -> Documents -> Detect when file is changed outside the environment`.

An effective way of dealing with this problem is to set up a simple build server, eg with [Jenkins](http://www.jenkins-ci.org) that kicks off a build periodically after there have been some checkins. If the build fails then the person who checked in gets a mail to tell them they broke the build. You can also have a monitor that shows the [build status](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Radiator+View+Plugin) which makes broken builds more visible to the whole team and hopefully encourages everyone to keep the build fixed.